# API Gateway, Lambda, NestJS URL Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nestjs, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have the following for my NestJS handler:

```
import { configure as serverlessExpress } from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

let cachedServer;

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

    await nestApp.init();

    cachedServer = serverlessExpress({
      app: nestApp.getHttpAdapter().getInstance(),
    });
  }

  return cachedServer(event, context);
};
```

and my API Gateway looks like:

[image]

Heading to my stage URL invokes the Lambda as expected, however, I am getting a NestJS 404 Error:

```
{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /account","error":"Not Found"}
```

My stage URL is: `https://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev_WvmpShJe/account`

I feel like I might be missing something to do with the `/account` route, but I'm not sure if this is something in API Gateway or the NestJS application itself. any ideas?